# Chrome Extension - Sandbox pages in Manifest V3 prevent external URLs from loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

To program my Chrome extension I need external scripts, which is why I defined them using the content_security_policy and sandbox pages. As soon as I did that, it was no longer possible to navigate between the sandbox pages because Chrome blocked them.

manifest.json:

```
"sandbox": {
        "pages": ["dashboard.html", "settings.html"]
       },
       "content_security_policy": {
        "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js https://kit.fontawesome.com/aed6fb8201.js"
       }
```

dashboard.html:

```
<ul>
            <p class="nav-desc">MAIN MENU</p>
            <li><a class="active" href="dashboard.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-gauge"></i>
                    <p> Dashboard</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="#" href="settings.html">
                <i class="fas fa-gear"></i>
                <p> Einstellungen</p>
            </a>
        </ul>
```

Error Message: When Clicking "Einstellungen" to navigate to the settings.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GruEU.png)

this error appears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7ynb.png)

I tried other urls like google.com and this works. It looks like everything that isnt inside the sandbox pages array works

Any solutions to the problem? Thank you!

Comment: In addition, API commands on the Chrome API such as chrome.storage.local no longer work

Comment: Sandbox page is essentially a web page security-wise, so to link to another chrome-extension:// page you must expose it in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure this is just prohibited and even if you find a way to get this to work you will most likely not be allowed to publish in the store. Or, in other words, just download the scripts and include them in the bundle.

Comment: This is allowed by the web store.

Comment: You sure? This is from the docs:

In Manifest V3, all of your extension's logic must be part of the extension package. You can no longer load and execute remotely hosted files according to Chrome Web Store policy. Examples include:

Link: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/improve-security

Comment: Absolutely sure. Sandboxed pages are excluded from this.